# give a color to not a number

Tags: image, matlab, plot, missing-data

I have a matrix of integers, padded with `nans`

```
M=

 1     2     2     3     4     4
 2     2     2     3     4   NaN
 2     2     2     3     4   NaN
 2     2     2     3     4   NaN
 2     2     2     3     4   NaN
 2     2     2     3     4   NaN
```

I am plotting it using imagesc

```
imagesc(M)
```

However, if I plot it this way, `NaN` and `1` are shown with the same color, which is confusing.

How to have different colors for `NaNs` in `imagesc`?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the NaN to be transparent:

```
figure; imagesc ( M, 'alphadata', ~isnan(M) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `NaN` by 1 less than the minimum number in `M`:

```
t = M;
t(isnan(M)) = min(M(:))-1;
imagesc(t)
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct and actually is the one matching the original question. However, matlabgui solution is also very elegant